# В чем различие, в плане устройства, между виртуальным и не виртуальным деструкторами?

Tags: c++

Как работает виртуальный деструктор при наследовании мне известно. Мне интересен механизм работы.

Указатель на виртуальный деструктор также хранится в vtable? Если да, то порядок такой же как и у остальных виртуальных методов класса в таблице внутри vtable? или оно устроено как-то по-другому, есть отличие от виртуальных методов в способе хранения?

И как обстоит дело с обычным деструктором, он хранится как обычный метод?

Comment: Важные детали очень просты: если у вас невиртуальный деструктор, вызов `delete` по указателю на базовый класс ведёт к undefined behaviour. Всё остальное — детали имплементации каждого конкретного компилятора.

Comment: Наличие таблицы виртуальных методов не гарантировано стандартом. Поэтому если уж говорить о таблице виртуальных методов, то нужно говорит о конкретном компиляторе/компиляторах. Механизм точно так же не оговаривается стандартом, каждый компилятор имеет право на свою имплементацию.

Answer (score 5):

Разница в том, что если у вас планируется хоть какое-то наследование, то скорее всего будет создан объект потомка, на который будет указывать указатель на базовый класс.

```
Base * b = new Derived;
...
delete b;
```

И вот тут, если деструктор **не** виртуальный, будет вызван деструктор `~Base()`, что очень плохо... А если виртуальный - будет вызван деструктор `~Derived()`, что и требуется...

Так что главное правило - планируете наследование - делайте деструктор виртуальным!

Comment: Если деструктор базового класса не виртуальный, то после delete b будет вызван ТОЛЬКО деструктор базового класса, иначе будет вызван деструктор производного, а потом и базового, что и нужно.

Comment: Если полиморфного удаления не планируется, виртуальный деструктор не является обязательным несмотря на наличие иерархии классов.

Comment: @Александр Гм, а я что написал?..

Comment: @alexolut Знать все заранее - нереально. В какой-то момент программа будет переделана, и начнутся неприятности. Конечно, можно вообще наследование и т.п. вещи реализовать на чистом C, если быть достаточно аккуратным... но зачем? :) Так и тут - лучше обезопасить себя заранее...

Comment: @Harry по Вашей формулировке, можно подумать, что с виртуальным деструктором будет вызван только **~Derived()**

Comment: @Александр А разве деструктор производного класса не вызывает деструктор базового? Это же азы...

Comment: @Harry на мой взгляд, если человек спрашивает про виртуальный деструктор, то может быть не знаком с такими "азами".

Comment: @Александр ну, разве что...

Comment: @Harry, если ещё не читали Герба: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm (Guideline #4)

Comment: @alexolut  Это то же, что он писал в "Стандартах программирования на C++".

Answer (score 3):

Деструктор в интересуемой Вами части ничем не будет отличаться от обычной функции-члена. Если Вы используете объект производного класса через указатель на базовый класс в процессе его удаления через `delete`, то деструктор базового класса должен быть виртуальным. Вот и всё.

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ, Вы меня поняли чуть лучше остальных, но хотелось бы немножко подробней, я обновил описание вопроса.